# Why is boundedness necessary in this proof that addition and scalar multiplication are continuous maps in the metric space induced by a norm?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Why is boundedness necessary in this proof that addition and scalar multiplication are continuous maps in the metric space induced by a norm?

Suppose that $\lambda _n \to \lambda $, $\mu _n \to \mu $, $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$ and $\|y_n\| \to \|y\|$.

I'm confused by the following statement:

> **Noting that $\{||x _n |\} $ and $\{||y _n |\} $ are bounded**, and using property (ii) and (iii) of the norm, it is easily verified that
>
> $$\|(\lambda _n x _n +_mu _n y _n )-(\lambda x + \mu y )\|\to 0 $$

This seams to be a trivial fact from the triangle inequlity and absolut homogeniety of the norm. (And of course a convergent sequence is bounded.) Where do I need the boundedness?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are properties (ii) and (iii)?

Comment: Just write down the triangle inequality as used to estimate the left hand side

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes that is how I did it, but why do the author mention the boundedness?

Comment: What do you get when you use the triangle inequality? Typically, you get terms with a factor of $\lVert x_n\rVert$, and need the boundedness to conclude that it tends to $0$.

Comment: Thanks, this is trivial really. My mistake was to not even write it out, but thinking I could "see" the soultion in my head...